# Show only top-level bullet points of list as an overview

Tags: lists, enumitem

I have a list that looks like this:

- Overview of item 1

  - Part 1 of more in depth description of item 1
  - Part 2 of more in depth description of item 1
  - Part 3 of more in depth description of item 1
- Overview of item 2

  - Part 1 of more in depth description of item 2
  - Part 2 of more in depth description of item 2
  - Part 3 of more in depth description of item 2
- etc...

I'd like to, without having to copy and paste the items, have a separate list at the top of my document to show only the top-level items in the list to serve as an overview. So, the overview of the list above, would look like:

- Overview of item 1
- Overview of item 2
- etc...

To further clarify, my document looks something like:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Overview of item 1
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\Alph*)]
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 1
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 1
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 1
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Overview of item 2
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\Alph*)]
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \item etc...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I was wondering what an elegant way of doing this would be.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document to start with. And at first glance I think, copy and paste is easier, somewhat

Comment: If I only did one time, I'd agree with that. However, with the amount of updates that I need to do, it quickly becomes more of a hassle.

Comment: Are all lists just like the example? i mean not deeper then level 2.

Comment: The most I have are lists that go up to three or four deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (a trick)

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{mt}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\stepcounter{mt}\setbox\themt\vbox\bgroup}
\AfterEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\egroup\ifnum\value{mt}=1\unvbox1\fi\addtocounter{mt}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Overview of item 1 
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\Alph*)]
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 1
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 1
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 1
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Overview of item 2
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\Alph*)]
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \item etc...
\end{enumerate}

bla bla

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Overview of item A1
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\Alph*)]
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 1
         \begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)]
             \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 1.A
             \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 1.A
             \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 1.A
        \end{enumerate}         
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 1
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 1
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Overview of item A2
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\Alph*)]
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \item etc...A ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see where you're going with this, and this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. However, both examples only show the top-level items.

Comment: @zuramu sorry may be i don't understand the question isn't this what you look for?

Comment: @zuramu you want to show the top level list first and then the full list? is it?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to do, but this shows only the top-level list both times.

Comment: @zuramu sorry this is not what i understand i will try

Answer (score 2):

An intermediate version with automatic `\item` usage and the `\toplevel*` command wrapper, that ignores `\sublevel` commands then.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newif\ifsublevels
\sublevelstrue
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\sublevel}{m}{%
  \ifsublevels
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\item ##1}
  \end{enumerate}
  \fi
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\toplevel}{sO{}m}{%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{%
    \global\sublevelsfalse
  }%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {#3}
  \begin{enumerate}[#2]
    \seq_map_inline:Nn  \l_tmpb_seq {\item ##1}
  \end{enumerate}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\toplevel{Top item 1 \sublevel{Sub level 1, Sub level 2, Sub level 3}, Top Item 2 \sublevel{Sub level 11, Sub level 21}}

\toplevel*{Top item 1 \sublevel{Sub level 1, Sub level 2, Sub level 3}, Top Item 2 \sublevel{Sub level 11, Sub level 21}}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest defining a special environment for this application, which gives you more freedom for choosing what to show.

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{overview}[1]
 {\begin{enumerate}\relax
    \ifnum#1=0
      \let\do@suboverview\@gobble
    \else
      \def\do@suboverview##1{%
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]##1\end{enumerate}%
      }%
    \fi
 }
 {\end{enumerate}}
\NewEnviron{suboverview}{\do@suboverview{\BODY}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Short overview}

\begin{overview}{0}
    \item Overview of item 1
    \begin{suboverview}
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 1
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 1
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 1
    \end{suboverview}
    \item Overview of item 2
    \begin{suboverview}
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 2
    \end{suboverview}
    \item etc...
\end{overview}

\section{Long overview}

\begin{overview}{1}
    \item Overview of item 1
    \begin{suboverview}
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 1
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 1
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 1
    \end{suboverview}
    \item Overview of item 2
    \begin{suboverview}
        \item Part 1 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 2 of more in depth description of item 2
        \item Part 3 of more in depth description of item 2
    \end{suboverview}
    \item etc...
\end{overview}

\end{document}
```

As you see, passing from the short to the long overview only needs to change the argument to `overview`.

[image]